# Mongodb mongoose node js schema relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hello i am new on mongodb and node js i have a question

here is my product schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const categorySchema = require('./category');

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    country: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "country can't be null"]
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "name can't be null"]
    },
    measureValue: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    minPrice: {
        type:Number,
        required: [true, "minPrice can't be null"],
        min: [1,"minPrice must be at least 1"]
    },
    maxPrice: {
        type:Number,
        required: [true, "maxPrice can't be null"],
        min: [1,"maxPrice must be at least 1"]
    },
    photoUrl: {
        type:String,
        default: ""
    },
    explanation: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },
    category: [categorySchema.schema],
    userID: {
        type: String,
        required: [true,"userid cant be null"]
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    deletedDate: {
        type:Date
    }
})
```

and here is my category schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CategorySchema = new Schema({
 name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "name can't be null"]
    },
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    deletedDate: {
        type:Date
    }
})
```

i need to do this;
every product data must be have category

if one day,one category's name changed then every product that relation with that category must changed

i am trying to set category id to product schema and when i fetch the data it must be comes every product with category name as json

i am really confused if you help me i'd be really thankful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your category as :

```
category: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'category' //your model name
    }
```

You can wrap it into an array and name it categories if you want multiple categories.

Then when you get the data, you will have to execute `new Product().populate('category')` to get retrieve the category data instead of just returning the category ObjectId.

Comment: when i insert a new product
 should i send category id or category model ?

Comment: i want to send category id is this possible with this way ?

Comment: Yes you can send just the id

Comment: ProductModel.find({}).populate('Categories').exec(function(err,data)  {
        res.send({Result: data})
    })

i used this method but return data just like this

            "city": "",
            "measureValue": 0,
            "photoUrl": "",
            "explanation": "",
            "isActive": true,
            "createdDate": "2018-01-25T14:45:35.582Z",
            "_id": "5a69ed8f3151bd15b46920fc",
            "name": "bread",
            "minPrice": 4,
            "category": "5a69b854ca974d40ccc4b62d",
            "__v": 0

Comment: it just return category id not category model

Comment: when i post using this

{
 "country": "turkey",
 "category": "5a69b854ca974d40ccc4b62d",
}

Comment: Well, you are populating 'Categories' but your attribute name is 'category'...you have to do ```populate('category')```